# facebook like box content issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook

I am trying to integrate fb like box in my site. I am able to display same using fb like box code i get from facebook developer. but problem is like box content is not shown when am not logged in facebook. is there any way to show the like box content even when am not logged in facebook.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include your code? This should work!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the solution for this. 
Go to the facebook page--edit page--resources tab-- remove if provided any country there
                                                -- set age to 13+

Finally, copy this code to your website wherever needed with your pageid...

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?id=pageid&amp;width=234&amp;connections=10&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:600px"></iframe>
```